# Regex to find and remove char with specific pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string

```
This is mail@mail.text #1 but page is @001#
```

<sub>(001 is variable, ex 01a or 021 etc)</sub>

And I want to make it

```
This is mail@mail.text #1 but page is 001
```

With this `^@([0-9]{1,3})#\z` i can find a string that starts with "@" and ends with "#" with max 3 chars inside but it doesn't match inside a entire text.

Comment: Try `@([0-9]{1,3})#\z` and replace with `$1`. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%40%28%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c3%7d%29%23%5cz&i=This+is+mail%40mail.text+%231+but+page+is+%40001%23&r=%241). If the text you need to remove is inside the string, remove `\z`, too. Is `(001 is variable, ex 01a or 021 etc)` part of input?

Comment: Its a little unclear. Is the "(001 is variable, ex 01a or 021 etc)" part of your string or is that just comments on the string? You've quoted it as if it is part of the string but you talk about just matching the @001# part of the string while actually removing it from your desired results...

Comment: `^` means the match has to be at the start of the string, `\z` at the end. Simply remove both and it should be fine. (`@([0-9]{1,3})#`)

Comment: Ok sorry i make a mistake with marker "(001 is variabile..." is a comment. this is final solution @([0-9A-Za-z]{1,3})# , but maybe there is a better way to say "every char" inside @ and #? Thanks

Comment: If the `01a` is valid too, you should include `a-z` in your pattern too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `^` (start of the string anchor) and replace the match with the contents of Group 1 using `$1` backreference:

```
var str = "This is mail@mail.text #1 but page is @001#";
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"@([0-9]{1,3})#\z", "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%40%28%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%29%23%5Cz&i=This%20is%20mail%40mail.text%20%231%20but%20page%20is%20%40001%23&r=%241)

The `@([0-9]{1,3})#\z` pattern will find `@`, 1 to 3 digits (put inside a group), and then a `#` at the *very* end of string (`\z`).

Another variation: if the value may start with a digit and can be followed with an ASCII letter or digit, use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"@([0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]{0,2})#\z", "$1");
```

And if the value can just be alphanumeric, just use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"@([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,3})#\z", "$1");
```

Comment: If the pattern can occur anywhere in the text, remove the `\z` too.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in [my comment to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41828517/regex-to-find-and-remove-char-with-specific-pattern/41828677#comment70843780_41828517), but it seems the idea is to match the text at the end of the string.

Comment: For my case final solution is `@([0-9A-Za-z]{1,3})#`. Thanks!

Comment: It is not quite clear from the question, so I think the 3 approaches are worth mentioning. The third one is what works for you.